# counting characters

Tags: java, while-loop, character, switch-statement, counting

I am having a problem writing the code to make a while loop asking for user input as long as the user does not end "quit". When I run the code it just generates nothing but the First prompt question "Enter a sentence or a phrase: " and then after you enter the phrase it does not calculate the while statement. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

The question is:
"It would be nice to have the program let the user keep entering phrases rather than having to restart it every time. To do this we need another loop surrounding the current code. That is, the current loop will be nested inside the new loop. Add an outer while loop that will continue to execute as long as the user does NOT enter the phrase quit. Modify the prompt to tell the user to enter a phrase or quit to quit. Note that all of the initializations for the counts should be inside the while loop (that is we want the counts to start over for each new phrase entered by the user). All you need to do is add the while statement (and think about placement of your reads so the loop works correctly). Be sure to go through the program and properly indent after adding code—with nested loops the inner loop should be indented. "

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Count

    {
         public static void main (String[] args)
         {

              String phrase;    // A string of characters
              int countBlank;   // the number of blanks (spaces) in the phrase 
              int length;       // the length of the phrase
              char ch;      // an individual character in the string      

    int countA, countE, countS, countT; // variables for counting the number of each letter

    scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Print a program header
    System.out.println ();
    System.out.println ("Character Counter");
    System.out.println ("(to quit the program, enter 'quit' when prompted for a phrase)");
    System.out.println ();

    // Creates a while loop to continue to run the program until the user
    // terminates it by entering 'quit' into the string prompt.

        System.out.print ("Enter a sentence or phrase: ");
        phrase = scan.nextLine();

        while (phrase != "quit");
        {   
            length = phrase.length();



                // Initialize counts
                countBlank = 0;
                countA = 0;
                countE = 0;
                countS = 0;
                countT = 0;

                // a for loop to go through the string character by character
                // and count the blank spaces

                for (int i = 0; i < length ; i++)
                {
                    ch = phrase.charAt(i);

                    switch (ch)
                    {
                        case 'a':             // Puts 'a' in for variable ch
                        case 'A':  countA++;  // Puts 'A' in for variable ch and increments countA by 1 each time
                                    break;    // one of the variables exists in the phrase

                        case 'e':             // puts 'e' in for variable ch
                        case 'E':  countE++;  // ... etc.
                                    break;
                        case 's':
                        case 'S':  countS++;
                                    break;
                        case 't':
                        case 'T':  countT++;
                                    break;

                        case ' ':  countBlank++;
                                    break;
                    }

                }

            // Print the results
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.println ("Number of blank spaces: " + countBlank);
            System.out.println ();
            System.out.println ("Number of a's: " + countA);
            System.out.println ("Number of e's: " + countE);
            System.out.println ("Number of s's: " + countS);
            System.out.println ("Number of t's: " + countT);
            System.out.println ();



    }   
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem in two ways:

```
while (phrase != "quit");
```

Firstly, *don't* use `==` or `!=` for string equality checking. It only checks for *reference identity*.

Secondly, the `;` at the end means it'll keep looping forever. It's equivalent to:

```
while (phrase != "quit")
{
}
```

You want:

```
while (!phrase.equals("quit"))
```

You *also* want to ask for more input at the end of the loop. (Still within the loop body, but after the output part.) Or change the loop condition to loop forever, ask for input at the start, and then break if the input is "quit".

Comment: ok, so I did the two things that you said, but now it repeats the output generated at the end of the code repeatedly, over and over, when I want the code to re-prompt the user to enter a phrase or sentence, and then execute the while loop again until the user eventually enters "quit" in which case the program will terminate. My teacher said that the while loop had to come AFTER the scan.nextLine(); used to get phrase.

Comment: @TommyD: well you can't do it without having *something* which asks for the next line after displaying the first one.

Comment: probably that scan line needs to be inside the loop as well as before it

Comment: @JeffHawthorne: Indeed, as per my final paragraph - which I've now clarified :)

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks so much! I was forgetting to put the prompt at the end of the while statement! Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to collect input again inside your `while` loop. Put something like this at the end:

```
phrase = scan.nextLine();
```

Notice that you only get a value for `phrase` once -- before the while loop starts. After that, you never set it to anything else. After the output is performed, you need to collect another value for `phrase` (which could be equal to "quit").

EDIT: Also, what Jon said. Listen to him. He's... pretty smart.

Answer (score 0):

A map would be better choice here:

```
Map<Character, Integer> counter = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
```

```
for(int i = 0; i < length ; i++)
{
    ch = phrase.charAt(i);
    counter.put(ch, counter.get(ch) + 1);
```

```
int charACount = counter.get('A');
```